# Labels : Including a symbol, `:`, using a psuedo-element, `::after`, on the right hand side of an element

Tags: html, css, label

I'm trying to setup a form-like layout in HTML/CSS for displaying JSON data. I would like the labels to be left aligned, have a colon upon the right hand side and elide the text they contain if the element becomes to small to display all of it properly.

```
long label  :
long label :
long l... :
```

While I have a working implementation I was wondering it there was any means of getting rid of the extra `span` element within my HTML and CSS ?

#### Minimum Working Example:

Presently my strategy is to wrap the text within a `span` and wrap this within a `div` whose class is set to `label`. Ellidation is enabled upon the `span`, and it is set to fill most of the containing `div` less some space on the right for the symbol; colon, `:`, in this case. The `div` uses the psuedo-element `::after` to append the symbol. Lastly `display` is set to `flex` and `justify-content` to `space-between` to fill the horizontal space between the `span` and the symbol.

```css
    div {
     border  : 1px solid blue;
     outline : 1px solid invert;
     }
    div.label {
      /* Dimensions */
      width           :             20%;
      border-radius   :             5px;
      padding         : 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      /* Behaviour */
      clear           :            left;
      float           :            left;
      display         :            flex;
      justify-content :   space-between;
      /* Style */
      font-weight    :            bold;
    }
    div.label span {
      /* Dimensions */
      width : /* fallback */ 95%;
      width :  calc(100% - 10px); 
      /* Alternatively : margin : 0px 10px 0px 0px; */
      /* Behaviour */
      /* - Enable text-overflow */
      white-space   : nowrap;
      overflow      : hidden;
      /* Style */
      /* - Format text-overflow */
      text-overflow : ellipsis;
    }
    div.label:after {
      /* Contents */
      content   :   ":";
    }
    div.value {
      /* Dimensions */
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding :   3px;
      /* Behaviour */
      float   :  left;
    }
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="label"><span>Short label</span></div>
  <div class="value">Short string</div>
  <div class="label"><span>A very long label</span></div>
  <div class="value">A very long string, so long in fact that it will have to wrap more then one line, possibly even more if you have a sufficiently small screen</div>
</article>
```

(I did google about some but I can't seem to locate any examples that are better then my implementation, notably SO does not appear to have a related question/answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` with the pseudo element and you will be able to get rid of the extra `span` as you can move all the properties applied on the `span` to the `div`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 1px solid invert;
}

div.label {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px 13px 3px 3px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
   white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}


div.label:after {
  content: ":";
  position:absolute;
  right:3px;
}

div.value {
  /* Dimensions */
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  /* Behaviour */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="label">Short label</div>
  <div class="value">Short string</div>
  <div class="label">A very long label</div>
  <div class="value">A very long string, so long in fact that it will have to wrap more then one line, possibly even more if you have a sufficiently small screen</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried something similar at one point but couldn't get it to work.